# Copying multiple files of different file types UNIX

Tags: unix

I have some files that are .py and others that are ".txt". Instead of

```
cp *.py myDir/
cp *.txt myDir/
```

is there a way to perform this in one line on the command line?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cp *.{py,txt} myDir/
```

More info about *nix wildcards you can find [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm).